# Flex - Problem in passing parameter to a Servlet via. HttpService

Tags: java, apache-flex, image, servlets

I am new to flex and calling a Java servlet from a flex client using HttpService. I am facing some problem in passing a parameter whose value is an Object

Here is the flex code which captures an image from the webcam:

```
            :
            var bitmapImageContainer:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
            bitmapData = new BitmapData(localVideo.width,localVideo.height);
            capturedImage = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
            bitmapImageContainer.addChild(capturedImage);
            addElement(bitmapImageContainer);
            :

             public function captureImage():void {      
                if (localVideo != null) {
                    bitmapData.draw(localVideo);
                    saveImage.enabled = true;
                }
             }
```

And I am trying to send the captured image to the java servlet via. HttpService like below:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="service" url="http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/CapturedImageSaver" result="resultHandler(event)" fault="faultHandler(event)" method="POST" showBusyCursor="true" resultFormat="text">
        <s:request xmlns="">
            <image>{bitmapData}</image>
            <hello>value</hello>
        </s:request>
    </s:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>
```

**Questions**

**Q1.** Shall I send **bitmapData** or **capturedImage** object to the servlet?

**Q2.** At the server side (servlet), to whom I need to cast the received object from the client side?

**Q3.** At the server side (servlet), I am getting only one parameter i.e **hello**. Why I am not getting the second paramter i.e. **image**?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline parameters, just code it:

```
service.send({image:bitmapData,hello:value});
```

This should work, if your service isn't seeing it, it could be a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested your code, but it seems like you need to pass the bytes from the BitmapData as a byte array.  Here is one example of the conversion (you'll have to excerpt it yourself).

http://www.richardleggett.co.uk/blog/index.php/2006/08/11/getpixels

Hope that helps you out.  As far as how to decode on the server-side, you'll need to package the bytes into the right kind of mime wrapper.